# Pandas Select Rows from a dataframe with highest value within a category in separate column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a way of selecting the rows of a dataframe with the highest value within a group identified in a separate column.

DataFrame:

```
  Group     Value
0  A         0
1  A         12
2  A         22
3  A         63
4  B         0
5  B         24
6  B         66
7  B         78
```

Desired DataFrame:

```
  Group     Value
0  A         63
1  B         78
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use groupby and take the max

```
df.groupby('Group').max()
```

```
        Value
Group   
A          63
B          78
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby("Group").max()
```

Or

```
df.groupby("Group")["Value"].max()
```